# Cell events are not triggered

Tags: jointjs

I have a working paper with graph. I have added several cells to the graph and I'm trying to listen to the `cell:highlight` event but I never receive it.

I'm doing:

```
paper.on('cell:highlight', function() { ... });
```

Other events seem to work fine, for example: `blank:pointerup`,...

Is there something special to do to make cell events work ?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:

> `cell:highlight` - triggered when `highlight()` method is called on either
>   an element or a link. Note that this method is also called
>   automatically when the user is reconnecting a link and the connection
>   is valid (`validateConnection()` returns true) or if `embeddingMode` is
>   enabled on the paper and the dragging element is above another element
>   it could be dropped into (`validateEmbedding()` returns true). The
>   handler for this event has the following signature: `function(cellView,el)`. The handler defaults to `function(cellView, el) {
>   V(el).addClass('highlighted') }`. In other words, the 'higlighted' CSS
>   class is added and so you can style the highlighted element in CSS. If
>   you want to use a different method for highlighting cells, call
>   `paper.off('cell:highlight')` first to unregister the default handler
>   and then `paper.on('cell:highlight', myHandler)` to register your own.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper:events).